# ¿Cómo crear un JSON en php?

Tags: php, json

Estoy tratando de crear un archivo **JSON** en **PHP** para que se conecte con mi *app* en *Android*. Quiero que muestre el *array*, pero *Android Studio* tira *"not found"*, y al tratar de acceder a la página en el *host*, no aparece nada o igual marca error, ¿Qué está mal?

```
<?php

require_once(“JSON.php”);
$json = new Services_JSON;
$data = array(id => “ejemplo”, name => “ejemplo2”, email => "ejemplo3");
echo $json->encode($data);

?>
```

Comment: En `“JSON.php”` estás usando unas comillas gráficas, no son las comillas dobles `""`. Lo mismo en el array,

Answer (score 6):

Para crear un `json` a aprtir de un `array` en `php`, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
    $json = json_encode($dataArray);
    print_r($json);
?>
```

Te dejo un enlace a la documentacion oficial: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que buscas con la recompensa? Ya que tienes una respuesta que en teoría contesta a la pregunta.

Answer (score 2):

Si quieres un JSON de objetos este código te puede funcionar.

```
function mijson{
   $items []= array("title" => "book", "price"=>"19.99");
   $versiones = array("productos" => array($items));
   json_encode($items);     

   return $items;
}
```

Comment: Hola, podría explicar tu código por favor? :)

Comment: Te dice que en items[] esta definiendo como un objeto, al cual le da un valor de arreglo "array("title" => "book", "price"=>"19.99") psdata title y price son las cabeceras para el valor correspondiente ", después le asigna un arreglo a la variable items, en el cual crea un arreglo con cabecera productos y le asigna items.

Answer (score 2):

Yo ocupo la siguiente estructura para regresar un json con una validación en PHP pero lo puedes adaptar a tus necesidades:

- primeo hay que declarar la variable $json un arreglo
- la casilla "status" va a tener el valor ´ok´ y así con las siguientes casillas.

  ```
   `<?php
    $json=array();
    $json['status']='ok';
    $json['user']=$_SESSION['usuario'];
    echo json_encode($json);`
  ```

El resultado de mi ejemplo es: {"status":"ok","user":"Pablo"}

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Para hacer eso puedes tratar tu clase normalmente, y después hacer un parse con `json_encode`.

```
<?php
    $std = new stdClass();
    $std->nome = 'Json Parse';
    $std->url = 'http://es.stackoverflow.com';
    $std->data = '2016-10-28';
    $json = json_encode($std);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Php incluye por defecto funciones para manejar JSON, por lo que no tendrás que incluir ninguna externa (A no ser que prefieras hacerlo así).

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$data = ['id' => "ejemplo", 'name' => "ejemplo2", 'email' => "ejemplo3"];
echo json_encode($data);
```

También he incluido una cabecera (header) para indicar que lo que se va a mostrar es JSON y he cambiado la manera de definir el Array (A partir de PHP 5.4 se posibilita usar la sintaxis corta de array). En el caso de que tengas una versión anterior o igual a 5.4, te recomiendo que actualices a 5.6 ó 7.0 ya que versiones anteriores son discontinuadas por PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Hay diversas formas de crear mira yo lo hago así:

en primera instancia creo un **conection.php:**

```
<?php  
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
date_default_timezone_set("Chile/Continental");   
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "saltala");  
?>
```

y luego otro php llamado **consulta.php**

```
<?php      
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *')  
date_default_timezone_set("Chile/Continental");   
// Including database connections  
require_once 'conection.php';  
// mysqli query to fetch all data from database  
$query = "SELECT rut, numero, servicio_id FROM Tickets";  
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);  
$arr = array();  
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) != 0) {  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {  
$arr[] = $row;
 }  
}  
echo $json_info = json_encode($arr);  
?>
```

retornando finalmente en formato `JSON` los datos que solicite a mi db...

corre eso en un servidor local y veras que al abrir consulta.php en el navegador te mostrata todos los datos solicitados en JSON.

Saludos...

Answer (score 1):

Como comenta Mariano en los comentarios estas utilizando comillas gráficas “ ” en vez de utilizar " ". Si cambias las comillas gráficas por las normales, quedaría tu código de la siguiente forma:

```
<?php
    require_once("JSON.php");
    $json = new Services_JSON;
    $data = array(id => "ejemplo", name => "ejemplo2", email => "ejemplo3");
    echo $json->encode($data);
?>
```

Por otro lado para crear un **json** a partir de un array o de una clase, existe la función [**`json_encode`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) propia de PHP y para decodificar está la función [**`json_decode`**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php).

Te dejo a continuación unos ejemplos de cómo lo puedes hacer:

### **Ejemplo 1**

**json:**

> { 
>       "nombre ": "Prueba json",
>       "versiones": [
>                   ["froyo", "2.2"], 
>                   ["gingerbread", "2.3"]
>                ] }

**Codificación mediante clase:**

```
$obj = new stdClass();
$obj->nombre = "Prueba json";
$obj->datos= array(
    array("froyo","2.2"),
    array("gingerbread","2.3")
);

echo json_encode($obj);
```

### **Ejemplo 2:**

**json:**

> {     "versiones_android": [
>                   {"froyo":"2.2"},
>                   {"gingerbread":"2.3"}
>                   ] }

**Codificación mediante arrays:**

```
$versiones = array(
    "versiones_android" => array(
        array(
            "froyo" => "2.2"
        ),
        array(
            "gingerbread" => "2.3"
        )
    )
);
echo json_encode($versiones);
```

Answer (score 1):

Para crear un **JSON** con **PHP** debes utilizar la función **json_encode**, que básicamente lo que hace es **convertir** un **Array** **en** un **string** con el formato **JSON**.

Un Ejemplo:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json');//cabecera json
$array = array("animal"=>"perro", "animal"=>"gato", "animal"=>"elefante");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Revisa la documentación: http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php